# Why is Nash equilibrium stable?

Tags: game-theory

As I understand it, a Nash equilibrium is an equilibrium because no player can single-handedly improve their situation.

But now consider a game where one of the Nash equilibria is worse for TWO of the players. What is stopping these TWO players from switching to a better Nash equilibrium?

Now if the new Nash equilibrium has again at least two players for whom the previous equilibrium was better, what stops them from switching back?

Comment: In non cooperative games, player A cant trust the choices of player B.  This what stops these TWO players from switching to a better equilibrium.

Comment: I don't know much (if anything) on the topic, but I think that it was proven by Daskalakis (MIT) that Nash equilibrium does not exists.

Comment: @Frans "... no player can improve their situation by **unilaterally** changing strategies..."

Comment: Check out the notions of [coalition-proof Nash equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coalition-proof_Nash_equilibrium) and [strong Nash equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_Nash_equilibrium), they deal with this question.

Comment: @yoav_aaa would you mind writing an answer to explain this in detail? since all players have access to the payoff matrix, they should be able to switch right? Note that I am even constraining the switch to another Nash equilibrium (assuming it exists).

Comment: @Konstantin thanks for the links, the strong nash equilibrium seems very close to what I was looking for! But as the wiki notes, it doesn't always exist. Plus the wiki also notes "While the best-response property in Nash equilibrium is necessary for self-enforceability, it is not generally sufficient when players can jointly deviate in a way that is mutually beneficial." So I guess if strong Nash equilibrium doesn't exist and arbitrary coalitions are allowed, there are no equilibria?

Comment: @ps95 John Nash proved a theorem that says that a vanilla Nash equilibrium **always** exists. The wiki quote should be understood as *"best-response property (=self enforceability) guarantees that a candidate equilibrium is Nash,  but does not guarantee it is a strong Nash"*. ('cause you have to check collective best-responses for that, for all possible coalitions).

Comment: @Konstantin thanks, this is what i was looking for. so is it right to say that it is possible for some payoff matrix to be "unstable" if unrestricted cooperation is allowed? unstable as in players have no stationary strat.

Comment: @ps95 Yes, you get the point. But it is weird to speak of instability of payoff matrices. You just have some Nash equilibria that are not strong Nash equilibria. They are not equilibria if you allow agents to team up for deviations. Stationary strategies is also something from the dynamic games chapter, which there was no mention of.